# Can I set myself as Master Admin in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

We have some personnel that need access to our Google Analytics information. When I go to add them, though, it says that I do not have permission to do so.

I assume there is a higher-level Admin account than mine, but nobody seems to know what it might be. There were only three potential accounts that I could think of that might have that level of permissions, but none of them did.

The first potential was a general University account, but it seems to have the same permissions as mine. The second potential is the account of the third-party company that set up our site. They said that they did not have that level of permissions. The third was the account of our previous Social Media strategist, but he said that he does not have access anymore. If I had to guess, I'd say that his account was the "master account" and when he left, he removed his access, leaving only "standard admin" accounts.

Is there a way that I can set myself or a general University account as the "master admin" over the account? Does Google Analytics even use a "master admin" account?

Answer (score 1):

If your setup description is correct, than no, you can't become a master admin without of action of University admin.

The way you become a master admin or user with any other access level is:

- University admin logs in into GA account,
- and invites you by your email address to become a member of group with certain access rights,
- You get the invite, and after you accept it, you get delegated access rights.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Google to grant you the admin access of the account. Try from the Google Analytics help center to see how you can contact them. They will tell you how to prove you actually own the website/account. It has worked for me in a situation similar to yours.